# Using a slurm script to run other snakemake slurm jobs

Tags: python, slurm, snakemake, hpc

I have a functional snakemake profile for running jobs on the HPC using SLURM. If I run this script locally, the jobs are submitted in parallel and everything works as expected.

However, this pipeline takes a while, and I have to VPN into a protected environment to work with this data, so I cannot keep my terminal open forever as the VPN has a timeout.

So I would like to use an .sbatch script that can handle this for me. Minimally, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --account=<acct>
#SBATCH --partition=<part>
#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --output=./logs/log.out
#SBATCH --error=./logs/log.out

# Move to snakemake directory. 
cd path/to/workdir

# Make logs directory.
mkdir -p logs

# Load environment. 
ml miniconda3/latest
module use ~/MyModules
source /path/to/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate snakemake

# Run preprocessing pipeline.
snakemake --slurm --profile profile/cluster/
```

However, when I do this, my jobs fail with the error messages:
`srun: fatal: SLURM_MEM_PER_CPU, SLURM_MEM_PER_GPU, and SLURM_MEM_PER_NODE are mutually exclusive.`

This error does not happen when I launch snakemake right from the terminal, so the error shouldn't be in the profile itself.

How can I use an sbatch script to host the rest of the slurm job submissions?

Comment: Not experienced with `slurm`, but a few ideas: a.) Maybe remove `--slurm` or `--profile` and specify all information via one or the other option, they might be colliding. Preferably use `--profile`. b.) if the job is submitted, you shouldn't need to keep the terminal instance alive; the job should continue to run and finish, even if you interrupt your connection. c.) if you want to keep you terminal alive, can you use a terminal multiplier like `screen` or `tmux` instead? This way you can restore your terminal session when reconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not what you are asking exactly, I still think this might help you.
If the only problem is termination of ssh session, then I would suggest to start your workflow under a new terminal session with `screen`.

First, connect to your remote server.

Open a new session

```bash
screen -S your_chosen_name
```

Activate environment, start

```bash
conda activate env_name;
snakemake -j 48 ....
```

Now, if your ssh session will be terminated or you will close it by yourself, this task will be running under another terminal session. To reattach to it:

```bash
screen -r your_chosen_name
```

[More at Linux Screen Man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)

Answer (score 0):

have a look here!!!

apparently just assigning the '--mem=2G' to the sbatch job solves the issue have tested it!!!

https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2230